# Large $\forall$

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to get larger `$\forall$` symbol? Adding `\Big$` doesn't work.

Comment: `\Large $\forall$`

Comment: @Seamus: You mean `{\Large $\forall$}`. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is the most modest increment on Seamus' and Martin Scharrer's comments above: if you use it more than once, you may as well go ahead and define

```
 \newcommand\bigforall{\mbox{\Large $\mathsurround0pt\forall$}}
```

which will co-operate with the mathmode context you will likely be using the symbol in.

Comment: Don't forget the `\mathsurround=0pt`.